# mPDF dev download excludes files

Tags: php, github, mpdf

I'm using the mPDF library for PHP, but the current release is not compatible with PHP 7.  Various issue threads on Github suggest using the current Dev version; but it appears that simply downloading the Zip file excludes important files (including the /vendors/ directory and the autoload.php file.)

The developer seems impatient with people asking this question, and actually told somebody "go ask on StackExchange".  So... here I am.

How the heck do I download the entire package from the development branch?

Comment: have you ever heard about composer? I *think* you are supposed to run `composer install` on downloaded extracted project

Comment: Heard of it, but don't use it.  Can I really not just download a zip file??

Comment: Sadly, no. You are talking to someone of same mindset as you have. Except of you, I accepted my fate and started to use composer for stuff I need without actually understanding why

Comment: Make it an "Answer" and I'll mark it Correct.  Worked fine. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, the package you are trying to use is being installed through Composer

1. Install [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) to your machine if you did not do it previously
2. Unzip file to directory of your choice
3. Navigate to such directory in command line / terminal
4. Run `composer install`